# How to get hints about the encoding used to send form data (in PHP)

Tags: php, forms, encoding, character-encoding

Im working on a script that receives data via the POST method from forms on websites. The encoding is not known, but I'd like to use `mb_detect_encoding()` to detect the encoding of the Strings received.

Now are there ways to get additional hints of what encoding might have been used for sending the data? Browsers might see that the page is in `ISO-8859-1` and thus also send the data in that encoding and possibly add some HTTP-header to indicate the format.

What are typical sources to get charset hints?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect case for writing a webservice and a standardised API that others can code to rather than you accepting random public posts.

Comment: @Dave: Sure, but at the moment I need to cover the case where users do not supply their encoding (correctly). So every source that gives me a hint to the encoding should improve the detection by `mb_detect_encoding()`.

Comment: If you do it via web services then you shouldn't have to worry too much about encoding the problem is with detection its not fool proof, infact its very trivial for a browser to send you incorrect details. you'd probably be better off assuming its a full blown utf-8 and use that to cover 90% of potentials rather than direct detection.

Comment: @Dave: So my question is: which `channels` does a browser use to send (even potentially wrong) information about the charset used to send the data? Is there a header field I can parse, or a `$_POST` field that might be filled,...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not know the encoding, you've already lost. You need to make sure the encoding is as defined as possible. If the data is coming from a form, use the `accept-charset` attribute to specify a defined encoding; preferably UTF-8:

```
<form accept-charset='utf-8'>
```

On your server, use `mb_check_encoding` to *confirm* that the received data is indeed UTF-8 encoded as you requested. If it's not... it's up to you what you want to do. For all intents and purposes you have random garbage data on your hands; whether you can salvage that in any way depends on your situation and what you're trying to do with the data.

FWIW, browsers do *not* send any indicator for what encoding they're sending you. Some browsers (*cough*old IE*cough*) also don't always honour the `accept-charset` attribute, unless you force it to encode a non-ASCII character; sites tend to embed a hidden input with a snowman character ☃ or something similar Unicode-y in it for this purpose.

Further, if a browser, for whatever reason, doesn't encode the content in UTF-8 but tries to send non-ASCII content, it will typically send HTML entities instead. This is something you could try to detect.

Comment: this can also be accessed via $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET'] I believe but still relies on it being specified on the form side.

Comment: Accept-Charset lets the client (browser) specify what charset it expects the server to return. It does not intrinsically say anything about what charset the client used when sending data to the server.